# Multiple Spark-submit jobs error

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I' trying to run multiple Spark jobs on DSE Cassandra using

```
dse> bin/dse spark-submit --class com.testing /jarpath
```

but after starting one instance I get error in another instance.

```
WARN  2018-05-09 14:55:31,051 org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: 
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure 
that workers are registered and have sufficient resources.
```

I have 4 node cluster each with 4 cores and 6GB RAM each. So, for each spark job I have defined following paramaters :-

```
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
  .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
  .set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
  .set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
```

So, where I'm going wrong or what need to be tuned in order to run multiple spark jobs in parallel.

Comment: what cluster manager do you use?

Comment: check your spark master UI.. it will have list of all applications and resource usage

Comment: @undefined_variable - Thanks, my bad I was missing spark master UI . It clearly shows the status of available and used cores and RAM. Resolved the issue. Thanks for your support